# How to know what is in a certain console position, when clicking it

Tags: c++, console

I'm building a simple console checkers game and I'm currently trying to make it possible to move the pieces using the mouse. Currently, my board looks like the following image:

[image: board image]

I've already managed to get the coordinates of anywhere I click on the console (using event handling from the windows.h library) but now I would like to know if there's anyway of checking if there is anything written (or any output) on the position I clicked, and if there is, to check what it is that was printed on that position, in order to know if I clicked on a piece or on an empty board cell.

If this is of any importance, I'm considering the pieces as being the character B or P rather than the whole square.

I don't know if providing the code I have would be of any help so I'm gonna post none of it for now, but if it is needed, I'll provide.

I'm just looking for any input regarding the possibility of doing what I asked, not actual code solutions. Thank you

Comment: Console is not a good way to do graphics. It will fight you, and you will spend lots of your time fighting it back. Create a proper GUI app, and do your graphics there.

Comment: @Dialecticus Ok, thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [Magnum](https://github.com/mosra/magnum), [SFML](https://github.com/mosra/magnum), [SDL](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL). If you want to _draw directly with your code_ [NanoVG](https://github.com/memononen/nanovg) is an excellent project.